# Freeing squad members from slavery

Tags: kenshi

A squad member was captured and is now a slave.

I went to the slave traders at the stone camp he was in, but none of them had any slaves for sale. I tried going in there at night and breaking him free, but the guards somehow knew straight away and came to lock him up again. I don't have the manpower to destroy the whole camp. What are my options?

Answer (score 3):

While my character was a slave, a group of rebels attacked my group of guards while we were moving between areas. I used that opportunity to escape.

You can try luring a mob into the guards while they are moving between areas, and free your squadmate while the guards are occupied (you will have to undo the shackles and run away fast, as combat doesn't last that long)

While waiting for an opportunity, have your squadmate lockpick his cage every time he is in it. If his escape is not successful, they'll just put him back, otherwise, hey, he's free! (But he's still on the run so avoid soldiers)

However, it is possible for him to die while escaping if the guards do too much damage.

I will keep updating this answer with tricks I find.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know if slaves in stone camps ever leave the camp? Seems like it's pretty heavily guarded, so luring a mob into the camp itself might not be enough?

Comment: @Mitch After a while a caravan can pass and buy your character, making him move between areas, its your time to strike when that happens

Comment: Oh, cool. Is there a particular character icon visual I should keep an eye out for when that happens? I barely ever look at what the guy's doing. :)

Comment: @Mitch I updated my answer with something to do for your character while it is imprisoned. This will give you a reason to check up on him once in a while

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that out. So it's not possible to buy him back when at a stone camp?

Comment: @Mitch not sure, maybe he's just not for sale at that moment but he could be later on

Comment: My observation is that slaves are only sold by the slaver faction in their towns. Slave 'end users' (the ones the slavers normally sell their captured slaves to) don't sell slaves; they prefer to 'work them to death', although they may also transfer them around to different locations. Saving a slave can be risky, since even if you buy a slave from them, if a slaver guard see a slave they just sold to you not wearing shackles, they consider that a free pass to re-capture that slave and then sell them again.